# High latency on ping but ok one for traceroute on local network via wi-fi

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

I sshed to a local machine over wi-fi and experienced latency like I was working on a server on the other side of the world. The ping shows:

```
$ ping imac.local
PING imac.local (192.168.0.38): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=4.961 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=164.356 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=184.635 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=203.981 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=128.627 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=143.717 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=112.190 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=184.448 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=205.589 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.38: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=124.649 ms
```

However traceroute is magically quick:

```
$ traceroute imac.local
traceroute to imac.local (192.168.0.38), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.38 (192.168.0.38)  5.522 ms  4.412 ms  5.133 ms
```

It is not a fluke, I ran it multiple times and couldn't get a latency higher than 10ms. Any idea why ping and traceroute give different latencies?

Edit: It must be OSX specific. A PC laptop and the wifi router give me sub 10ms ping latencies, wheras pinging the two osx computers from each other give me the high latencies.

Comment: Run them (ping & traceroute ) in parallel. It possibly that when you measuring with `ping` WiFi network is overloaded/attacked/etc or better use `mtr` command in parallel with `ping`. You can also try UDP ping with `mtr` utility. Use some WiFi scanners and make sure you running on not too overcrowded channel that may influence your network.

Answer (score -1):

First, there are many factors that can interfere with wireless signals. For example, distance is too far or signal blocking.

Second, the working principle of ping and traceroute is different.

Ping sends an ICMP echo request message to the destination and reports whether it receives the desired ICMP echo (ICMP echo response). It is a command to check if the network is fluent or the speed of the network connection. Principle: Using the uniqueness of the machine's IP address on the network, send a packet to the destination IP address. Then ask the other party to return a packet of the same size to determine whether the two network machines are connected, and what is the delay.

When the host uses the traceroute command, it first sends a packet containing an IP header and a UDP packet. When passing through a router, the router will decrement the value of the TTL of the IP header and the IP header in the ICMP header by 1. When the TTL value of ICMP is 0, the router will discard the datagram and return the timed ICMP packet to the source host.  After receiving the time-out ICMP packet, the source host adds 1 to the TTL of the IP header in the previous ICMP to continue sending IP datagrams until the destination address receives an IP datagram with a TTL value of 1. The destination address does not discard the datagram and return the timeout ICMP message. At this time, the source host will parse the UDP packet in ICMP. The UDP packet usually uses a port that is not available to the receiving end, so the target host will return a "port unreachable" ICMP message. It is mainly used to distinguish whether the ICMP packet is timed out or the port is unreachable. When the source host receives an ICMP packet with an unreachable port, it knows that the route tracking is completed.

You can refer to this [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/12778-ping-traceroute.html) for detailed information.
Understanding how ping and traceroute work can help you understand your problem better.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this answer is wrong/misleading in multiple ways. The first is that the problem is clearly not related to WIFI interference as the performance is reproduceable. The second is that your assertions about the working principles of ping and traceroute - while in some ways correct is misleading (there are multiple ways of doing ping for a start) - and the post does not answer the question.